# Python Error Message: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python

In my python code, I am getting below error. can someone please let me know how to solve this

```
key_split = key.rsplit('.', 1)
return key_split  +  "_thumbnail.png"
```

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: `rsplit` returns a `list`, so if you want the first element of this list, you'd do `key_split[0]  +  "_thumbnail.png"` and so on.

Comment: What is the input and the expected result?

Comment: In your own words, when you do `key.rsplit('.', 1)`, what do you expect the result to look like? Why? Now, did you test that? What do you actually get? Do you understand why? Does it make sense to you to concatenate the string to that result? Why or why not?

Comment: Python makes it easy to experiment. Before the error, add `print(repr(key_split))` and you'll see a list. Then its a question of figuring out how it got there.

Comment: @Daniel: Thank you for your response. I am trying to concatenate file name. 
let take example: I have file called (abcdef.png), and i upload that file into drive. then code will read that filename and place the new file with file name (abcdef_thumbnail.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `key_parts` is a list (see below), and you can only concatenate two lists or two strings, not a string and a list.

Here is an example illustrating a possible solution (which the comments have already hinted at):

```py
key = 'io.0i'
key_parts = key.rsplit('.', 1)  # ['io', '0i']
file_name = key_parts[0] + '_thumbnail.png' # io_thumbnail.png
```

Comment: When i take " key_parts[0]......" then the script is picking a newly generated file as well and creating massive junk. is there any way we can ignore the file name contains  "_thumbnail"

Comment: Check if the file exists before creating it? https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that key_split is a list

To solve the problem:
`return "".join(key_split) + "_thumbnail.png"`

The way this works is that the `join` keyword joins the items in the list placing whatever is in the `""` before `.join()` in between all the items

Comment: When i take use this method then the script is picking a newly generated file as well and creating massive junk. is there any way we can ignore the file name contains "_thumbnail"

Comment: You could do: `if  "_thumbnail"  not in key_split: return "".join(key_split) + "_thumbnail.png"` This will ignore the file if it already includes `"_thumbnail" `

Comment: This is current code , how can i able to mention if condition here
def new_filename(key):
    key_split = key.rsplit('.', 1)
    return "".join(key_split) + "_thumbnail.png"

Comment: Just before the return statement should do the trick. Or you could do it right after the `def new_filename(key):`. Add `if "_thumbnail" not in key:`